# Moxy - Creating XML element with no corresponding Java Property

Tags: xml-serialization, marshalling, moxy

I've been using Moxy to successfully marshall / unmarshall complex xml types into a more simple java Structure. In particular, I'm working with ISO Pain 20022 messages and there are a number of fields that are present in the XML that we don't care about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iso:Document xmlns:iso="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.04" >
    <iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <iso:GrpHdr>
           <iso:MsgId>OriginalMessageID</iso:MsgId>
            <iso:CreDtTm>2013-05-29T20:02:22.615</iso:CreDtTm>
            <iso:NbOfTxs>1</iso:NbOfTxs>
            <iso:InitgPty/>
        </iso:GrpHdr>
       <iso:PmtInf>
...
</iso:Document>
```

Here is my oxm bindings file piece:

```
<xml-element java-attribute="messageId" xml-path="iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn/iso:GrpHdr/iso:MsgId/text()"/>
<xml-element java-attribute="creationDateTime" xml-path="iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn/iso:GrpHdr/iso:CreDtTm/text()"/>
```

I need to generate the additional two xml elements *iso:NbOfTxs* and *iso:InitgPty* which will always be the same and there is no corresponding property for these on the java class that is generating the xml.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307430/insert-additional-fields-in-jaxb-marshalling for a few suggestions on how to do this with MOXy.

Answer (score 0):

I am still working on this use case.  Below is the XML I am currently able to generate (I recognize that it's not correct).

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iso:Document xmlns:iso="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.04">
   <iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <iso:GrpHdr>
         <iso:MsgId>OriginalMessageID</iso:MsgId>
      </iso:GrpHdr>
   </iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
   <iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <iso:GrpHdr>
         <iso:CreDtTm>2013-05-29T20:02:22.615</iso:CreDtTm>
         <iso:NbOfTxs>1</iso:NbOfTxs>
         <iso:InitgPty/>
      </iso:GrpHdr>
   </iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</iso:Document>
```

**Document**

Below is a simplified version of your domain model:

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class Document {

    private String messageId;

    private Date creationDateTime;
}
```

**oxm.xml**

In the metadata below I'm trying to use an `XmlAdapter` to convert the `Date` property into a more complex object that can write out the other 2 XML elements.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum16839007">
    <xml-schema
        namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.04"
        element-form-default="QUALIFIED">
        <xml-ns prefix="iso" namespace-uri="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.04"/>
    </xml-schema>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Document" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
            <xml-root-element name="Document"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="messageId" xml-path="iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn/iso:GrpHdr/iso:MsgId/text()"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="creationDateTime" xml-path=".">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="forum16839007.ExtraAdapter"/>
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**ExtraAdapter**

Here is the `XmlAdapter` that converts a `Date` into a more complex object.

```java
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

public class ExtraAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ExtraAdapter.Extra, Date>{

    public static class Extra {

        @XmlPath("iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn/iso:GrpHdr/iso:CreDtTm/text()")
        public Date creationDateTime;

        @XmlPath("iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn/iso:GrpHdr/iso:NbOfTxs/text()")
        public final int NbOfTxs = 1;

        @XmlPath("iso:CstmrCdtTrfInitn/iso:GrpHdr/iso:InitgPty/text()")
        public final Empty initgPty = new Empty();
    }

    public static class Empty {
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(Extra extra) throws Exception {
        return extra.creationDateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public Extra marshal(Date date) throws Exception {
        Extra extra = new Extra();
        extra.creationDateTime = date;
        return extra;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum16839007/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Document.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum16839007/input.xml");
        Document document = (Document) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(document, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise, your summary captures my classes fine. In the end I had to revert to putting in some additional methods on the model class to get over this hump. Would be great to see this kind of functionality in moxy.