# Force Add attribute to soapRequest

Tags: soap, jaxb

A soap request is built with jaxb. The structure of one element is missing an attribute after the all components have been built for the request. I can not determine how to add the specific attribute below so the attentionLine element looks like this:

```
<attentionLine>
    <keyWordText>FIRSTTEXT</keyWordText>
    <value xsi:type="ST">SECONDTEXT</value>
</attentionLine>
```

If I change the types defined in the **AttentionLine** class (code below) for the types originally specified to **String** type then the element can appear like this:

```
<attentionLine>
    <keyWordText>FIRSTTEXT</keyWordText>
    <value>SECONDTEXT</value>
</attentionLine>
```

The **AttentionLine** classes and other relevant pojo classes are attached below. These were generated from the wsdl and schemas.

I do not follow how to do add an attribute like **xsi:type="ST"**. Also the **value** element is shown as **ANY** type in the **AttentionLine** class or even when I have changed the type to **String**.

My requests contains many elements and structures. In most cases the generated code works as expected. The developer of the soap api recommended not to use the generated classes at all. Please identify if there is a simple solution to add the attribute or if I should apply one of the suggestions from the @bdoughan response to this question:
[Insert additional fields in JAXB marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307430/insert-additional-fields-in-jaxb-marshalling).

---

AttentionLine.java
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2
// See http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema.
// Generated on: 2023.10.10 at 12:33:25 PM EDT
//

```
package com.ours.test.ws.transfer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for AttentionLine complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="AttentionLine">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;group ref="{urn:hl7-org:v3}InfrastructureRootElements"/>
 *         &lt;element name="keyWordText" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}SC" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="value" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}ANY" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attGroup ref="{urn:hl7-org:v3}InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
 *       &lt;attribute name="nullFlavor" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}NullFlavor" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AttentionLine", propOrder = {
    "realmCode",
    "typeId",
    "templateId",
    "keyWordText",
    "value"
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
public class AttentionLine {

    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected List<CS> realmCode;
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected II typeId;
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected List<II> templateId;
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected SC keyWordText;
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected ANY value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "nullFlavor")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected List<String> nullFlavor;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the realmCode property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the realmCode property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getRealmCode().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link CS }
     * 
     * 
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public List<CS> getRealmCode() {
        if (realmCode == null) {
            realmCode = new ArrayList<CS>();
        }
        return this.realmCode;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the typeId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link II }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public II getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the typeId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link II }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setTypeId(II value) {
        this.typeId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the templateId property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the templateId property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getTemplateId().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link II }
     * 
     * 
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public List<II> getTemplateId() {
        if (templateId == null) {
            templateId = new ArrayList<II>();
        }
        return this.templateId;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the keyWordText property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link SC }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public SC getKeyWordText() {
        return keyWordText;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the keyWordText property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link SC }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setKeyWordText(SC value) {
        this.keyWordText = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ANY }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public ANY getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ANY }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setValue(ANY value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the nullFlavor property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the nullFlavor property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getNullFlavor().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public List<String> getNullFlavor() {
        if (nullFlavor == null) {
            nullFlavor = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.nullFlavor;
    }

}
```

---

ST.java

```
package com.ours.test.ws.transfer;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * 
 *             The character string data type stands for text data,
 *             primarily intended for machine processing (e.g.,
 *             sorting, querying, indexing, etc.) Used for names,
 *             symbols, and formal expressions.
 *          
 * 
 * <p>Java class for ST complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ST">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{urn:hl7-org:v3}ED">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="reference" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}TEL" maxOccurs="0" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="thumbnail" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}ED" maxOccurs="0" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="representation" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}BinaryDataEncoding" fixed="TXT" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="mediaType" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}cs" fixed="text/plain" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="language" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}cs" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ST")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    SC.class,
    ENXP.class,
    ADXP.class
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
public class ST
    extends ED
{


}
```

---

ED.java
package com.ours.test.ws.transfer;

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;


/**
 * 
 *             Data that is primarily intended for human interpretation
 *             or for further machine processing is outside the scope of
 *             HL7. This includes unformatted or formatted written language,
 *             multimedia data, or structured information as defined by a
 *             different standard (e.g., XML-signatures.)  Instead of the
 *             data itself, an ED may contain 
 *             only a reference (see TEL.) Note
 *             that the ST data type is a
 *             specialization of 
 *             when the  is text/plain.
 *          
 * 
 * <p>Java class for ED complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ED">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{urn:hl7-org:v3}BIN">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="reference" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}TEL" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="thumbnail" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}thumbnail" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="mediaType" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}cs" default="text/plain" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="language" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}cs" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="compression" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}CompressionAlgorithm" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="integrityCheck" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}bin" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="integrityCheckAlgorithm" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}IntegrityCheckAlgorithm" default="SHA-1" />
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ED", propOrder = {
    "reference",
    "thumbnail"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ST.class,
    Thumbnail.class
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
public class ED
    extends BIN
{

    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected TEL reference;
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected Thumbnail thumbnail;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "mediaType")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected String mediaType;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "language")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected String language;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "compression")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected CompressionAlgorithm compression;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "integrityCheck")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected byte[] integrityCheck;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "integrityCheckAlgorithm")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected IntegrityCheckAlgorithm integrityCheckAlgorithm;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the reference property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link TEL }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public TEL getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the reference property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link TEL }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setReference(TEL value) {
        this.reference = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the thumbnail property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Thumbnail }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public Thumbnail getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the thumbnail property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Thumbnail }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setThumbnail(Thumbnail value) {
        this.thumbnail = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the mediaType property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public String getMediaType() {
        if (mediaType == null) {
            return "text/plain";
        } else {
            return mediaType;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the mediaType property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setMediaType(String value) {
        this.mediaType = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the language property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the language property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setLanguage(String value) {
        this.language = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the compression property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link CompressionAlgorithm }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public CompressionAlgorithm getCompression() {
        return compression;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the compression property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link CompressionAlgorithm }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setCompression(CompressionAlgorithm value) {
        this.compression = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the integrityCheck property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     byte[]
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public byte[] getIntegrityCheck() {
        return integrityCheck;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the integrityCheck property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     byte[]
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setIntegrityCheck(byte[] value) {
        this.integrityCheck = ((byte[]) value);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the integrityCheckAlgorithm property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link IntegrityCheckAlgorithm }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public IntegrityCheckAlgorithm getIntegrityCheckAlgorithm() {
        if (integrityCheckAlgorithm == null) {
            return IntegrityCheckAlgorithm.SHA___1;
        } else {
            return integrityCheckAlgorithm;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the integrityCheckAlgorithm property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link IntegrityCheckAlgorithm }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setIntegrityCheckAlgorithm(IntegrityCheckAlgorithm value) {
        this.integrityCheckAlgorithm = value;
    }

}
```

---

BIN.java
package com.ours.test.ws.transfer;

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * 
 *             Binary data is a raw block of bits. Binary data is a
 *             protected type that MUST not be used outside the data
 *             type specification.
 *          
 * 
 * <p>Java class for BIN complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="BIN">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{urn:hl7-org:v3}ANY">
 *       &lt;attribute name="representation" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}BinaryDataEncoding" default="TXT" />
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BIN")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ED.class
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
public abstract class BIN
    extends ANY
{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "representation")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected BinaryDataEncoding representation;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the representation property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BinaryDataEncoding }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public BinaryDataEncoding getRepresentation() {
        if (representation == null) {
            return BinaryDataEncoding.TXT;
        } else {
            return representation;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the representation property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BinaryDataEncoding }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public void setRepresentation(BinaryDataEncoding value) {
        this.representation = value;
    }

}
```

---

ANY.java
package com.ours.test.ws.transfer;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * 
 *             Defines the basic properties of every data value. This
 *             is an abstract type, meaning that no value can be just
 *             a data value without belonging to any concrete type.
 *             Every concrete type is a specialization of this
 *             general abstract DataValue type.
 *          
 * 
 * <p>Java class for ANY complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ANY">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;attribute name="nullFlavor" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}NullFlavor" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ANY")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    SLIST_TS.class,
    SLIST_PQ.class,
    BL.class,
    ANYNonNull.class,
    CR.class,
    URL.class,
    CD.class,
    GLIST_PQ.class,
    GLIST_TS.class,
    QTY.class,
    BIN.class,
    II.class
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
public abstract class ANY {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "nullFlavor")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    protected List<String> nullFlavor;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the nullFlavor property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the nullFlavor property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getNullFlavor().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2019-08-30T12:53:15-04:00", comments = "JAXB RI vhudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-2")
    public List<String> getNullFlavor() {
        if (nullFlavor == null) {
            nullFlavor = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.nullFlavor;
    }

}
```